# Pointer and local variable in C

Tags: c, pointers

Can someone explain why this code works:

```
void changeValue(int **ptr) {
    int y = 19;
    *ptr = &y;
}

int main() {
    int x = 14;
    int *ptr = &x;
    printf("%d\n", *ptr);
    
    changeValue(&ptr);
    printf("%d\n", *ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Output is `14`, `19`, but how? As I understood `y` is local variable that gets vanished after function is done. So `*ptr` should point to nothing (empty space)? Obviously this isn't correct because this code works fine. Can someone explain me this?

Comment: Welcome to the beautiful world of undefined behaviour: since you hold on to the address of a local variable beyond its lifetime, your code is not spec-conformant so the compiler can basically do whatever it wants. You just "happen to get" a behaviour that looks like the variable is still around. If you had called some other methods between `changeValue` and the `printf` then odds are that you'd get something else.

Comment: Try calling another function between `changeValue(&ptr)` and `printf("%d\n", *ptr)`, and you will likely see different behavior. Perhaps even just calling `printf("%d\n", *ptr)` again would cause the value to change.

Comment: you are basically in luck to get the proper value, because something else didn't override it. this is indeed undefined behavior as mentioned in the above comment

Comment: As for what actually happens, `ptr` is pointing to some memory. That memory doesn't cease to exist when the lifetime of the variable ends. The memory still exists, and `ptr` is still pointing to that memory. If you call another function that memory will likely be reused, and the contents of the memory will change.

Comment: "should point to nothing (empty space)?" There is no such thing as "nothing" or "empty space" in C. A pointer always points somewhere. And that memory always contains some value if the address is a valid address.

Comment: @Lukic - The local variable *will* "vanish" when the function ends, but nothing says that the value has to go away *immediately*. You are not allowed to try to read it though.

Comment: @Lukic If you are using gcc or clang, compile with `-g -fsanitize=address,undefined` and then run your program and you'll get a report saying `stack-use-after-return` @ `printf("%d\n", *ptr);` which is a good indication of that your initial understanding was indeed correct. It's just that memory doesn't just go up in smoke so while it's undefined behavior to dereference `ptr` after the call to `changeValue` it may actually be able to fetch the value that was written to `y`.

Answer (score 1):

To understand the particular effect beyond framing it as just UB, you have to reason about the storage of the `y` variable. It is probably stored in the local stack frame of the `changeValue` function. When this function returns, we are back in the stack frame of the `main` function. At that point, the `y` variable is indeed out of scope, but its corresponding frame is probably not yet overwritten by another function invocation - it resides "under" us.

If you were to call, say, `foo` after `changeValue` that probably wouldn't be the case and you would get some random garbage.

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to work as expected, but as you wrote, it has undefined behavior and could result in anything else, including abnormal program termination, different output, or system failure.  Undefined behavior means anything can happen, including expected behavior, which is the most difficult to debug as the behavior can change in other circumstances...

Comment: There must be a duplicate for this.... though I admit that it is not in my dupe library yet.